# Hydrate entities with json data in Symfony2

Tags: json, entity, symfony

Is there any way to hydrate entities with json data from an incoming request in Symfony2?
I thought there was something similar to

```
Form::bindRequest
```

But I can't find anything... 
It would be nice to have this feature for using with libraries like knockout js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you need is to hydrate objects from a JSON (or XML) format, you can take a look at the [Serializer component](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer).

It was made to solve this kind of common problem.

You can even try the [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/) that makes the use of this component easier.

About validation, as it's another component (Validator), you can use it appart of the forms:

```
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$violdations = $validator->validate($myModel);

if (0 === $violations->count()) {
    // ok !
} else {
    // there are some constraint violations...
}
```