# symfony2 : hydrate a form with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, symfony

I am using symfony2 and I have a list of entities and a single form used to edit them.

So far i am using a route attribute to hydrate the form with one of the entities;

I understood here [Hydrate entities with json data in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442853/hydrate-entities-with-json-data-in-symfony2) that you can serialize the data to hydrate the form with ajax so I wouldn't have to reload the whole page?

I am familiar with ajax but could someone give an example on how the hydrating part is done? (format of the response and handling it to hydrate any kind of form if possible)
Can I update the route, preset the form field data generically (not for one particular form) ?

Thanks a lot